# How do I write a self join that includes rows with conditions that might not always be present

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, join, key-value

The following query for ticket orders will drop rows that don't contain a G.meta_key value of 'pa_co-creation' as not every ticket type has this value. How can I re-write this query to not drop those rows?

```
SELECT A.meta_value, B.meta_value, D.order_item_name, E.meta_value, F.meta_value, G.meta_value, H.meta_value, I.meta_value, J.meta_value, K.meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta A, wp_postmeta B, wp_woocommerce_order_items D, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta E, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta F, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta G, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta H, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta I, wp_postmeta J, wp_postmeta K
WHERE A.post_id = B.post_id AND B.post_id = D.order_id AND D.order_item_id = E.order_item_id AND E.order_item_id = F.order_item_id AND F.order_item_id = G.order_item_id AND G.order_item_id = H.order_item_id AND H.order_item_id = I.order_item_id AND A.post_id = J.post_id AND J.post_id = K.post_id
AND A.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' AND B.meta_key= '_billing_last_name' and D.order_item_type = 'line_item' And E.meta_key = 'pa_cabin-preference' AND F.meta_key = '_qty' AND G.meta_key = 'pa_co-creation' AND H.meta_key = 'pa_food' AND I.meta_key = 'pa_gluten' AND J.meta_key = '_billing_email' AND K.meta_key = '_billing_phone' AND D.order_id > 1014
```

Comment: Try and describe what is it that you actually want to achieve. The only sensible answer to the question you have asked is - remove the `AND G.meta_key = 'pa_co-creation'` from the query. And I suspect this is not what you need.

Comment: @fdreger Some orders do not contain a 'pa_co-creation' value and the above query when adding `AND G.meta_key = 'pa_co-creation'` will output only orders that have that value. OR does not seem to do the trick...

Comment: Please provide ample data and desired results.  Your query is also rather impenetrable because you are using *implicit* joins.  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: First, read up on JOINs.

Comment: @Strawberry got a link? I've read a ton so far.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In all the documentation I have read I have never not seen a comma used in a clause where `FROM` lists multiple tables. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @ConnorPatrickDoran . . . A good place to start, then, would be the MySQL documentation on `JOIN`:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite a massive query.  So, it doesn't make sense for somebody answering you on SO to rewrite the whole thing for you.

WordPress, with its WooCommerce extension, uses a key-value-store patttern to store arbitrary metadata.  As you've discovered, it takes some finesse to preserve rows in result sets when some metadata is missing.

You need `LEFT JOIN` for this. (You're using the old comma join syntax: you're partying like it's 1999.)

Here's an example taken from a bit of your query.

Start with a table containing a row for every row you want in the result set. In WordPress, this is likely to be wp_posts.

```
SELECT Z.post_id ...
  FROM wp_posts Z
```

Then start joining the metadata like this

```
SELECT Z.postId, A.meta_value, ...
  FROM wp_posts Z
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta A ON Z.post_id = A.post_id AND A.meta_key = '_billing_first_name'
```

and keep going in with that pattern until you've LEFT JOINed each item of metadata, and you'll be partying like it's 2018.

Why does this work? Because ordinary JOIN (of which comma-join is a flavor) supresses rows from your result set that fail the JOIN condition. But LEFT JOIN preserves those rows and presents NULL values in place of the missing value.

Comment: Thank you @o-jones! This did the trick. This was the final query: https://imgur.com/QXqalHi

Comment: Well, more like 1992.